# Is it possible for a reference to be GC'd that is currently being consumed by a `using` block?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Given,

```
using (var abc = new Abc())
{

    // abc is not used here at all.

 }
```

Is it possible the abc is garbage collected before the ending curly brace?

Comment: `using` blocks have absolutely **nothing** to do with garbage collection.

Comment: @KirkWoll, it sort of does - lifetime of the object that is used in `using` is extended (explained by rally25rs), unlike regular {} blocks where object used in the beginning can be GC'ed in the middle of the block. Clearly it is because object is actually used outside of the block, but one needs good understanding of both mechanism to get it right.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, the same could be said of any block statement that consumes an expression (`lock`, `foreach`, etc.).   In all cases, the statement itself is hanging onto the expression for the duration of the block, but I think it's a real stretch to say that this somehow means such statements *in particular* have anything to say about garbage collection.

Comment: @KirkWoll, agree. I just wanted to highlight that "nothing" may be too strong. Even on more subtle impact: using `using` normally impacts GC is a way that the object in `using` will likely not be put in Finalization queue since Dispose will be properly called on it in all cases (again try/finally + correct Dispose).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no. internally, there is a reference held to `abc` until the ending curly brace.

The generated IL code looks like this:

```
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void ConsoleApplication1.Abc::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  .try
  {
    IL_0007:  nop
    IL_0008:  nop
    IL_0009:  leave.s    IL_001b
  }  // end .try
  finally
  {
    IL_000b:  ldloc.0
    IL_000c:  ldnull
    IL_000d:  ceq
    IL_000f:  stloc.1
    IL_0010:  ldloc.1
    IL_0011:  brtrue.s   IL_001a
    IL_0013:  ldloc.0
    IL_0014:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
    IL_0019:  nop
    IL_001a:  endfinally
  }  // end handler
```

When the `using` statement is turned in to IL code, the compiler actually translates that to a full `try / finally` block, and calls the `.Dispose()` method on your instance of `Abc`. So basically it turns it into something like:

```
Abc abc = new Abc();
try
{
}
finally
{
    abc.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, its scope is from opening braces to closing braces of `using` and `lock` blocks. So between those two braces it is very much there and is not Garbage Collected whether you are using it or not.

Comment: +1 after my edit :). Note that regular  {} blocks don't have this behavior.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: +1 from me to your comment.